# Add padding before and after each line of center-aligned text

Tags: html, css

I want this layout:

[image: Desired layout]

So I tried this:

```html
<h2>Make search awesome using Open Source</h2>
```

```css
.banner .section_title h2 {
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background: #176072;
}
```

But I am getting this result:

[image: Current output]

So, I want to add that padding (the red circle). How can I do that?

For the responsive design, I want this result:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: are you wanting open source to be on the same line if the page allows for it?

Comment: Do add your complete html.. or create a fiddle

Comment: What I want is in the first picture.

Comment: @RinoRaj The OP has provided enough code. Additional code would only clutter the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh just use CSS3 box shadows to emulate the padding on either side of each line:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.section_title {
  text-align: center;
}
.section_title h2 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: #176072;
  box-shadow: -.5em 0 #1D758C, .5em 0 #1D758C;
}
```

```html
<div class="section_title">
  <h2>Make search awesome using Open Source</h2>
  <p>A different color box-shadow is used for illustration.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works best after I found a problem in the last code(css outline)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution. Wrap the components that you want on separate lines with a `span` or `div` element. This will you to style the sections of text independently but keep the full text within a heading tag.

```html
<h2><span>Make Search Awesome Using</span> <span>Open Souce</span></h2>
```

```css
h2 span {
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background: #176072;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
}
h2 {
    background-color: #062949;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcpo5rmj/

**Note:** This is not a complete responsive solution.

Comment: Update your question to reflect a responsive request along with defining how you would like a responsive solution to work. Once done I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

To **dynamically** keep the padding on your text you need to use the CSS `outline` property:

```css
body {
  background-color: #033569;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #176684;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  outline: 5px solid #176684;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Make search awesome using Open Source</h2>
  <p>Click Full Page button then resize the browser</p>
</div>
```

Or view the example and adjust the container width in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae72L8jj/)**.

Container width at 200px below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the best option :)

Comment: But sometimes I am getting a pixel line in the text... Please see the pixel before "A" in the attached picture http://i.imgur.com/e7P9Ap8.png

Comment: It's probably just a glitch with the rendering or with your zoom settings on your browser. It looks fine from my browser when I looked at your actual page. I used both Chrome and Safari on Mac and I don't see that pixel line.

Comment: May be. But finally I have used the box-shadow method(answered by Salman) and it works best. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

best i could do https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/91j10osv/3/ - not responsive sorry

```
<div class="banner">
    <div>
        <h2>Make search awesome using</h2>
        <h2>Open Source</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="banner">
    <div>
        <h2>Make search awesome using&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Open Source</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="banner">
    <div>
        <h2>Make search awesome using<em></em><br/>
            <em></em>Open Source</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.banner div{
    text-align:center;   
}
.banner h2, .banner p{
    font-family:"Oswald", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background: #176072;
    color:white;
}
.banner h2:first-of-type{
    margin-bottom:0.2em;
}
em{
    width:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**html code...**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="holder">
    <h2>&nbsp;Make search awesome using&nbsp;</h2>
    <h2>&nbsp;Open Sources&nbsp;</h2>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**css code**

```
body{
    margin:0;
}


div.holder{
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div.holder h2{
    font-family:"Oswald", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background: #176072;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 80px;


}
```